# Session management and sliding expiration

Tags: c#

Default session time out is 20 minute. If some one interact with web page just before session time out which has been idle for long time then what will happen. Session time out will receed I mean increase or session will time out after 20 minute.

I heard session time out is based on sliding expiration. so tell me due to sliding expiration session time out increase?

If increase then how much it will increase...is it next 20 minute?

Please discuss about the nature of session time out and how sliding time out works. How session time out increase due to sliding time out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sliding expiration means that each time the session is accessed it will reset the timer back to 20 minutes again.

Comment: Sliding expiration is default behaviour or not. do i need to write any code for attaching Sliding expiration with session? please guide. thanks

Comment: Yes by default sliding expiration is used so you dont need to write any code

Comment: is there any way by which i can off the Sliding expiration as a result user access session or not the session will expire after 20 minute or 10 minute. can u guide me. thanks

Comment: If the user does not access the session for the timeout period then the session will expire.  If he user accesses the session at 3:01 then the session will expire at 3:21.  If the user accesses the session at 3:10 then the session will then expire at 3:30.  It is always 20 minutes after the user last accessed the session (that is the meaning of sliding expiration).  If the user does not access the session in that 20 minutes then the session will expire.

Answer (score 1):

`Sliding expiraton` will reset the expiration time each time when session is accessed.That is according to your question if the session is accessed in the middle then  again the timeout is set to 20 minutes.

Comment: Sliding expiration is default behaviour or not. do i need to write any code for attaching Sliding expiration with session? please guide. thanks

Answer (score 0):

if timeout = 120 mins

If a user visits his account then sliding expiration value will be reset and from that point, his session will be counted.
If a user does not perform any activity within 2hrs then his session will be expired.